# Performance issue in Camel cxf 2.20.0

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf

Environment :Camel 2.20.0

Java 1.8

Hit rate : 150hits/second

We are trying to upgrade our Camel version to 2.20.0 but we encouter some troubles and memory leak between camel-cxf 2.19.5 and 2.20.0.

We have a Camel route (exposing a CXF Endpoint) which write the payload in a file thanks log4j and move it every 15s in another folder.

The second Camel route read the file from the other folder and split it (and do some Processor).

In our test, the split just log the message "****** FOO BAR ****".

Due to the upgrade of the cxf library, our server crash outOfMemory and the garbage Collector isn't efficient as in the 2.19.5 version.

Is there any change between the 2 versions ?
Is there any configuration to change to keep our server stable ?

We can see these troubles (in 2.20.0) in VisualVM that the memory graph increase until the maximum memory and crash.

Thanks in advance.

First route exposing the CXF

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="frontalSupervision" address="/supervision" endpointName="s:supervisionSOAP" serviceName="s:supervision"
                wsdlURL="wsdl/supervision.wsdl" xmlns:s="http://*****/supervision/">
                <cxf:properties>
                    <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD" />
                    <entry key="receiveTimeout" value="${ws.cxf.receiveTimeout}"/>
                </cxf:properties>
                <cxf:inInterceptors>
                    <ref bean="supervision-authentication" />
                </cxf:inInterceptors>
            </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

<routeContext id="webservice-to-log4j2-route-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="webservice-to-log4j2-route">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:frontalSupervision" />

        <!-- permet de logger le contenu de la requete -->
        <to uri="log:body?level=DEBUG" />

        <process ref="log4j2LoggerProcessor" />
    </route>
</routeContext>
```

-
The seconde route :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <routeContext id="log4j2-to-bdd-route-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <route id="log4j2-to-bdd-route">
            <from
                uri="file:///{{messages.log.directory}}/{{messages.log.rolling.relative.directory}}?delete={{messages.files.delete}}&amp;antInclude={{messages.log.filename}}*.log&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll={{messages.maxmessageperpoll}}&amp;sortBy={{messages.sort.by}}&amp;delay={{messages.delay}}" />
            <split streaming="true" parallelProcessing="true"
                executorServiceRef="splitExecutor">
                <tokenize token="{{messages.xmltype.name}}" xml="true" regex="true"/>
            <log message="******* FOO BAR *****" />
            </split>
        </route>
    </routeContext>

</beans>
```

Comment: You could try to upgrade to [Camel 2.20.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=12341590&projectId=12311211) which upgraded [CXF to 3.2.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12310511&version=12341566) and see if this fixes your problem. 2.20.2 and 2.20.3 also contain a couple of fixes in regards to CXF. A general rule of thumb is to profile your application or take a heapdump and see what's polluting your memory to tell whether Camel or CXF or maybe also an unnoticed change on your side lead to the problem

Comment: We were initially in Camel 2.21.0 but we had to downgrade until we find the source of the problem, which is Camel 2.20.0 with CXF 3.2.0.

Comment: Our code didn't change during the upgrade.
The heapdump show us this : 
One instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 854 437 352 (90,36%) bytes. 
The instance is referenced by org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultInflightRepository @ 0xc19bf558 , loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0xc00a9668".

Comment: Problem solved : 
upgrade to Camel 2.22.0 to fix the CXF library